# Openpyxl saving currupted file ,android

Tags: python, tkinter, openpyxl

I have made a tkinter code to save staff to xlsx file, the program is working in my computer, but when I run it in my phone using pydroid3, the code runs without problems, but the file is corrupted and doesn't work.

Does anyone have an idea? I think the problem is that `wb.save('file.xlsx')` is saving the file in a corrupted form.

Code:

```py
from _tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from datetime import datetime
wb = load_workbook('file.xlsx')
sheet = wb.active
ht = 500
wt = 500
root = tk.Tk()
var = tk.StringVar()
var.set(datetime.date(datetime.now()))
def call():
    n = 4
    j = d.get() + " 00:00:00"
    while True:
        a1 = sheet.cell(row=n, column=2)
        if j == str(a1.value):
            break
        n = n + 1
    p1 = sheet.cell(row=n, column=3)
    p1.value = e2.get()
    c1 = sheet.cell(row=n, column=4)
    c1.value = e6.get()
    m1 = sheet.cell(row=n, column=5)
    m1.value = e1.get()
    E1 = sheet.cell(row=n, column=7)
    E1.value = e4.get()
    D1 = sheet.cell(row=n, column=8)
    D1.value = e5.get()
    a1 = sheet.cell(row=n, column=9)
    a1.value = e3.get()
    t1 = sheet.cell(row=n, column=11)
    t1.value = e7.get()
    f1 = sheet.cell(row=n, column=6)
    f1.value = e8.get()

w = tk.Canvas(root, height= ht, width= wt)
w.pack()
frame= tk.Frame(root,bg='#3363F9')
frame.place(relwidth=1,relheight=1)
d = tk.Entry(frame,textvariable=var)
d.place(relx=0.6,rely=0.15)
# sc = tk.Label(frame,textvariable=var)
# sc.place(relx=0.4,rely=0.1)
s1 = tk.Label(frame,text="math")
s1.place(relx=0.15,rely=0.25)
e1 = tk.Entry(frame)
e1.place(relx=0.35,rely=0.25)
s2 = tk.Label(frame,text="physics")
s2.place(relx=0.15,rely=0.30)
e2 = tk.Entry(frame)
e2.place(relx=0.35,rely=0.30)
s3 = tk.Label(frame,text="arabic")
s3.place(relx=0.15,rely=0.35)
e3 = tk.Entry(frame)
e3.place(relx=0.35,rely=0.35)
s4 = tk.Label(frame,text="English")
s4.place(relx=0.15,rely=0.4)
e4 = tk.Entry(frame)
e4.place(relx=0.35,rely=0.4)
s5 = tk.Label(frame,text="German")
s5.place(relx=0.15,rely=0.45)
e5 = tk.Entry(frame)
e5.place(relx=0.35,rely=0.45)
s6 = tk.Label(frame,text="Chemistry")
s6.place(relx=0.15,rely=0.5)
e6 = tk.Entry(frame)
e6.place(relx=0.35,rely=0.5)
s7 = tk.Label(frame,text="transportion")
s7.place(relx=0.15,rely=0.55)
e7 = tk.Entry(frame)
e7.place(relx=0.35,rely=0.55)
s8 = tk.Label(frame,text="food")
s8.place(relx=0.15,rely=0.6)
e8 = tk.Entry(frame)
e8.place(relx=0.35,rely=0.6)
b = tk.Button(frame,text="get",command= lambda :call())
b.place(relx=0.75,rely=0.2)

root.mainloop()
wb.save('file.xlsx')
```

Comment: Oh man that wall of widget creation is a bit much. Please look into `grid()` or `pack()`. The `place()` geometry manager is not normally used like this and I don't think it really ever should be. You can create them in a loop and save them to a list. That said `wb.save('file.xlsx')` is after `mainloop()`. That line of code will only execute after the mainloop terminates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have cleaned up your code a bit and tested. No corruption on my end. Let me know if it helps.

1st we store all the label names in a list. Then looping through that list we use the ndex and value to create out entry and label widgets. We use the ndex to manage our grid. `place()` is not great for widget placement because if you need to make any changes you may end up having to rewrite ever single place to compensate. Then simply update the cell values with the correct index of the entry list. There was also no need for a canvas here. It appears all it was used for was color.

Example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from datetime import datetime
from openpyxl import load_workbook


ht = 500
wt = 500
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(ht, wt))
root.config(bg='#3363F9')
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
var = tk.StringVar()
var.set(datetime.date(datetime.now()))


def call():
    n = 4
    j = d.get() + " 00:00:00"
    wb = load_workbook('file.xlsx')
    sheet = wb.active

    while True:
        a1 = sheet.cell(row=n, column=2)
        if j == str(a1.value):
            break

        n = n + 1

    sheet.cell(row=n, column=3).value = entry_list[1].get()
    sheet.cell(row=n, column=4).value = entry_list[5].get()
    sheet.cell(row=n, column=5).value = entry_list[0].get()
    sheet.cell(row=n, column=6).value = entry_list[7].get()
    sheet.cell(row=n, column=7).value = entry_list[3].get()
    sheet.cell(row=n, column=8).value = entry_list[4].get()
    sheet.cell(row=n, column=9).value = entry_list[2].get()
    sheet.cell(row=n, column=11).value = entry_list[6].get()
    wb.save('file.xlsx')


frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='#3363F9')
frame.grid(row=1, column=1)

label_list = ["math", "physics", "arabic", "English", "German", "Chemistry", "transportation", "food"]
entry_list = []

for ndex, label in enumerate(label_list):
    tk.Label(frame, text=label, bg='#3363F9', fg='white').grid(row=ndex+2, column=0, sticky='e')
    entry_list.append(tk.Entry(frame))
    entry_list[-1].grid(row=ndex+2, column=1)

d = tk.Entry(frame, textvariable=var)
d.grid(row=0, column=2)
tk.Button(frame, text="get", command=call).grid(row=1, column=2)
root.mainloop()
```

That said we can reduce this further if you are ok with change some of the columns around in your excel file. If you would match the columns with the labels in order then you could do this instead:

```
def call():
    n = 4
    j = d.get() + " 00:00:00"
    wb = load_workbook('file.xlsx')
    sheet = wb.active

    while True:
        a1 = sheet.cell(row=n, column=2)
        if j == str(a1.value):
            break

        n = n + 1

    for i in range(8):
        sheet.cell(row=n, column=i+3).value = entry_list[i].get()
    wb.save('file.xlsx')
```

Comment: That actually works thank you , I'm a beginner in python and this is my first project with tkinter and the problem was despite my mess code that I should have putted the wb.save('file.xlsx') in my call function and that worked